# Как послать атрибут с пробелом в RouterOS API?

Tags: api, mikrotik

Скрипт такой:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import sys
import socket
from collections import defaultdict
from python_rosapi.Carbon_RosAPI import CarbonAPICore
from python_rosapi.Mikrotik_Errors import *
from optparse import OptionParser
from functools import wraps
import errno
import os
import signal


class TimeoutError(Exception):
    pass


class TimeoutWithContext:
    def __init__(self, seconds=1, error_message='Timeout'):
        self.seconds = seconds
        self.error_message = error_message

    def handle_timeout(self, signum, frame):
        raise TimeoutError(self.error_message)

    def __enter__(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, self.handle_timeout)
        signal.alarm(self.seconds)

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        signal.alarm(0)


def hendle_args():
    usage="Usage: %prog [options] nas_ip nas_login nas_password  [mikrotik command]\nExample: send_mikrotik_cmd 10.0.0.2 admin passw /ip firewall address-list add list=koko address=0.0.0.0"
    parser = OptionParser(usage=usage)

    parser.add_option("-d", "--debug", dest = "debug", help = "turn on debug mode", action="store_true", default=False)
    parser.add_option("-s", "--sensitive", dest = "sensetive", help = "it makes me sensitive to all errors and warnings", action="store_true", default=False)
    parser.add_option("-v", "--verbose", dest = "verbose", help = "it makes me talkative", action="store_true", default=False)
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    if len(args) < 4:
        parser.error("incorrect number of arguments")

    return (options, args)

(options, args) = hendle_args()

def prepare_commands(raw_command):
    debug("preparing commands raw: %s" % raw_command)
    cmd_lines = ' '.join(raw_command)
    cmd_arr = map(lambda st: st.strip(), cmd_lines.split(";"))

    prepared_commands = []
    for cmd_line in cmd_arr:
        cmd=cmd_line.split(' ')
        context = "/".join(filter(lambda st: not '=' in st, cmd))
        opts = [ w if "?" in w else "="+w for w in filter(lambda st: "=" in st, cmd) ]

        prepared_commands.append([context] + opts)
    debug("pprepared commands: %s" % prepared_commands)
    return prepared_commands

def mikrotik_try_connect(nas_ip, nas_login, nas_password):
    debug("trying to connect  to %s with login: %s" % (nas_ip, nas_login))
    try:
        mikrotik = CarbonAPICore(nas_ip, DEBUG=options.debug)
        mikrotik.login(nas_login, nas_password)
    except socket.error as e:
        sys.stderr.write("%s\n" % e)
        exit(254)
    debug("connection completed")
    return mikrotik

def pretty_response(responses):
    for response in responses:
        response_keys = sorted(list(set(sum([ x.keys() for x in response ], []))))
        str = "%(" + ")s %(".join(response_keys) + ")s"
        response = [ defaultdict(lambda:'-', line) for line in response ]
        for r in response:
            print str % r

def send_commands(mikrotik, commands):
    responses=[]
    for command in commands:
        try:
            response = mikrotik.response_handler(mikrotik.talk(command))
        except MikrotikError as e:
            err_msg="%s, command: '%s'" % (e, ' '.join(command))
            if e.warning() and not options.sensetive:
                if options.verbose: sys.stderr.write(err_msg+"\n")
                continue
            else:
                sys.stderr.write("%s exit code: %s\n" % (err_msg, e.get_exit_code()))
                exit(e.get_exit_code())
        responses.append(response)
    return responses

def debug(str):
    if options.debug: print "DEBUG: %s" % str

def main():
    nas_ip = args.pop(0)
    nas_login = args.pop(0)
    nas_password = args.pop(0)
    with TimeoutWithContext(seconds=60):
        mikrotik = mikrotik_try_connect(nas_ip, nas_login, nas_password)
        commands = prepare_commands(args)
        responses = send_commands(mikrotik, commands)
        pretty_response(responses)

main()
```

Там бездумный реплэйс пробела на слэш. В команде отправляю `%20` вместо пробела.  Доработал парсер немного, но микротик не принимает такую команду:

```
def kavychki(s):
    if '%20' in s:
        return s.replace('%20',' ').replace('=','="')+'"'
    else:
        return s

cmd = map(kavychki, cmd)
```

Comment: Дайте пример команд, которые отсылаете, там не такой синтаксис, как в терминале.

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh скрипт во вложении. дело не в том как послать команду, как там прописать пробел правильно? можно пример с пробелом?

Answer (score 0):

При использовании RouterOS API пробелы в значениях никак не экранируются, всё, что идёт после символа `=` и есть значение. Причём это правило действует как для запроса, так и для ответа.

Вот пример полностью рабочего запроса:

```
/interface/bridge/port/print
=.proplist=interface,bridge
?bridge=name with space
```

Ответ на этот запрос:

```
!re
=interface=ether3
=bridge=name with space

!re
=interface=ether4
=bridge=name with space

!re
=interface=ether5
=bridge=name with space

!re
=interface=ether6
=bridge=name with space

!re
=interface=ether7
=bridge=name with space

!re
=interface=ether8
=bridge=name with space

!re
=interface=ether9
=bridge=name with space

!done
```

Как это выглядит в Winbox:

[image: Winbox]